# How to display MySQL table using php and edit it in a web browser

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am using a while loop to display all the data in my MYSQL table. the problem is that its not showing the newest entry. after adding a record it does not show the record in my browser, but it would have been added in the database. 
 it will show after i add another one. i have attached pictures.

[image]

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
  <table id="t02" width="100%" border="1px">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ec Number</th> 
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                    </tr>
            <?php 

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM lecturer";

            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td>".$row['ecnumber']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['phonenumb']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['dept']."</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }

            ?>


                </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

Advances you to the second row everytime. Remove the first `fetch` call. Everytime you `fetch` you advance one row. So for example:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
print_r($row);
```

would print the third row.

Comment: how do i do that i am new on stack overflow

Comment: There should be a check mark next to the vote mark, here's a link that shows details https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: i just did Thanks

Comment: how do i delete or edit directly that record without going to the phpmyadmin database?